# embed html form to php code

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, statements

I have a form on on html outside of php...

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="user"/></br>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="login"/> 
</form>
```

then call submit button from php and do this

```
if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {

            print <<<this

    <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="apply"/>
            </form>
this;


             if(isset($_POST["apply"]))
             { print "it works";}


    }
```

Alright, so the problem is that, "it works" won't print from the second form thats inside the php. it just takes me back to where i came from. Perhaps it's a dumb question, please help though! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by the time you're checking `if(isset($_POST["apply"]))` the login condition becomes invalid because everything is inside the `if(isset($_POST["login"]))`.

Try taking the `if(isset($_POST["apply"]))` outside the login IF.

Answer (score 0):

Your "apply" code exists only INSIDE the `login` test code. When you submit that second form, there will be **NO** `login` form field, because you didn't include an input/textarea of that name in the second form. So the second form submits, there's no `login`, and the entire inner code never gets executed. You probably want:

```
if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
            print <<<this

    <form method="post" action="" name="apply">
        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="foo" /> <!-- add this line -->
        etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you wanna do with this code but you obviously missed some details :

_You did not set the "action" field in your form tag, so I don't understant how you would like the PHP file to get called ?
_Your code `if(isset($_POST['login']))` has no sense, you are testing the existence of a value sent by a validation button, you'd rather whrite `isset($_POST['user'])`

Hoping to have helped you

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are declared in 2 forms, so there will be 2 calls (completely independant) to your php.

So you could have a second submit button inside your second form:

```
if(isset($_POST["login"]))
{

        print <<<this
<form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Second"/>
        </form>

this;


}
if(isset($_POST["apply"]))
{ print "it works";}
```